# Automapper set destination element to an empty list object

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new to using automapper in C#, but I want to know how I can set a value in my map to element to an empty list.

So, in the ForMember where you map your from and to, I want to be able to do to create a new object and use that object to be a list which is empty. How can you do this in automapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `.ForMember()` and `.UseValue()`

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping config

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foos, m => m.UseValue( new List<Foo>() ));
```

Usage

```
var source = service.GetItem();
var dest = Mapper.Map<Dest>(source);

Assert.IsTrue(dest.Foos.GetType() == typeof(List<Foo>));
```

Comment: Cheers  but as my object is a complex type how would it let instantiate the type and then the list?

Comment: Instantiate which type? AutoMapper is providing a new instance of the destination type based on the values from the source type.

Comment: My list isn't a string or a long. So, for example,  myobject someType = new myobject(); and use it on creating a list

Comment: Use the appropriate type for your collection.